# Wiring grounds from two separate circuits

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

I am trying to build a rack that has two loads and each load will be powered from a separate circuit. Please see my diagram for reference. Grounding the two enclosure boxes is pretty straightforward.

It is not clear to me how the load enclosure box should be grounded since there are two circuits that feed into the load enclosure to power the two loads. Can the two grounds be wired together at the load enclosure?

[image]

Comment: What is this rack? Is this actually a DIY home improvement project? Powering one device from two separate feeds is often improper - generally one single disconnecting means is required for the whole device.

Comment: It's fairly common, @nobody, for server-grade computers to actually have 2 power supplies, and not uncommon for them to be supplied by different circuits. This allows the server to continue running should one PSU die or breaker trip. Not really sure if this is what the OP is doing, but it's not entirely unheard of. Your comments are valid and valuable, though, and caution should be taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can connect grounds from multiple circuits together. In fact, you *should* do so if they're in the same box.

The ground is only there for safety should something go wrong, and in this case, you'll have a "backup" in case one of the grounds somehow isn't sufficient.

**2023 NEC 250.148(A) Connections and Splices:**

> All equipment grounding conductors that are spliced or terminated within the box shall be connected together. Connections and splices shall be made in accordance with 110.14(B) and 250.8 except that insulation shall not be required."

Comment: It is pretty clear. 2023 NEC 250.148(A) Connections and Splices
"All equipment grounding conductors that are spliced or terminated within the box shall be connected together. Connections and splices shall be made in accordance with 110.14(B) and 250.8 except that insulation shall not be required."

Comment: Thanks you, @NoSparksPlease! I know ~~most~~ ~~many~~ _some_ of the right answers, but I don't know the code refs to go with them. I wouldn't have minded you editing that in directly, but I've done so now.